# AutoSizeColumn works for all columns but columns containing datetime values

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am creating an Excel file using NPOI.

I declare the sheet this way:

```
        var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(title);
```

The Excel is populated with data. The relevant part is when I set a date & time value:

```
                        if (data is DateTime)
                        {
                            cell.CellStyle = GetDateTimeStyle(workbook, true, GetCustomFormatForColumn(column));
                            cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToDateTime(data));
                        }
```

where cell is `ICell cell = row.CreateCell(column);` and `GetDateTimeStyle` method is:

```
    private ICellStyle GetDateTimeStyle(XSSFWorkbook wb, bool useBorder, string customFormat)
    {
        if (!_styles.TryGetValue("DATETIME", out ICellStyle style))
        {
            style = wb.CreateCellStyle();
            style.SetFont(GetItemFont(wb));

            style.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            if (useBorder)
                SetBorder(style);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customFormat))
                style.DataFormat = wb.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat(customFormat);
            else
                style.DataFormat = wb.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            _styles.Add("DATETIME", style);
        }

        return style;
    }
```

After all cells are populated, I run this `for` loop:

```
        column = 0;
        foreach (string header in columnNames)
            sheet.AutoSizeColumn(column++);
```

After that, resulting Excel has all columns autosized but column that contains the date and time values.

The cells containing date and time values are expanded in width but there are some pixels left to be expanded in order to display the whole date and time instead of just `#########`.

Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: have you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055519/how-to-set-autosize-to-excel-sheet-column-npoi.

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab have you read the full body of my question?

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark but have you tried `AutoFit` instead of `AutoSize`?  I think it handles word wrapping and truncation differently but I have not tested.

Comment: @jstuardo yes i read it before, i resrarch for a solution, sorry man if i got confuse. I was trying help.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I have not found AutoFit method nor property. Where is it?

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab no problem

Comment: It might not be in NPOI... `myRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();`  Here are [some other examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects) under step #4.