# NPOI. Expand width of excel file when it opens

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Could you explain me, I make excel file from datatable using npoi. Could I expand columns when file opens to header content lengths.

```
 using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(FileName))
        {
            workbook.Write(fs);
 }
```

Comment: did you try `AutoSizeColumn` yet?. please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651803/7889129 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151841/7889129

Comment: @Maddy please post your comment as answer so OP (Julia) can mark as answer? If Julia has accepted the answer, so can mark this question as closed. Thanks. (I am not moderator, just a reminder from fellow developer.)

Answer (score 1):

please try `AutoSizeColumn` to set **Autosize** to all columns.

`mySheet.AutoSizeColumn(columnIndex)`

please check

[“AutoSize” to Excel sheet column? (NPOI)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6651803/7889129)

and

['autosize' in Excel documents created with NPOI?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3151841/7889129)